# Add class to element base on sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I add a class to the p tag if the next tags that follows is an unordered list?

Sample mark-up:

```
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<ul>
   <li>line 1</li>
</ul>
```

So the first p tag has no class, and the second p tag would have class 'foo' since the next element after it is an unordered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it the other way round; target the `ul`, and select the previous elements of the contained `ul`'s **if** they are `p`'s, and add a class to them.

```
$('ul').prev('p').addClass('foo');
```

See the [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) method for more info.

Comment: Would this get the immediate previous element, or the first p element before each ul element? It seems like you want to get the previous element, then do a check if the element tag is p. Oh, no it doesn't, I missed a line about midway down the page you supplied. Nice answer!

Comment: @abelito: `prev()` returns the previous element **if** it matches the selector. If you want the previous `p`, you'd use `prevAll('p').first()`